# How to calculate expected value and variance of a random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, distribution-theory, density-function

Let the random variable $Y$ have the following density:

$$f(y) = \frac{1+\beta y}2, -1 \le y \le 1, -1 \le \beta \le 1$$

Find $E(Y)$ and $V(Y)$.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange! Generally we don't like to have questions in links. I've gone ahead and edited the question into the post.

Comment: Placing the question on hold seems awfully drastic.  It is obvious the question is being put by someone who is just beginning a course in probability theory.  The supplied answer is something that is usually given early in any probability course taken after elementary calculus.

Answer (score 1):

$E(Y^k)=\int_{-1}^1y^kf(y)dy$.  $V(Y)=E(Y^2)-E(Y)^2$.  I presume you can do the calculations.